# is there any way to type "+" in text field?

Tags: html, grails

```
when i type "name+2" in text field and submit i get "name 2" in my controller

is there any way to send "name+2" like html decoded... i dono....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you use GET request ? POST request should not have such problem, as the parameter will not be encoded in HTML way.

Answer (score 1):

```
&#43; Returns + in HTML
```

Try This, It should work in your Code.

Comment: both of us don't want to type &#43; instead of + in out text field